# Timer check Winform topmost enabled

Tags: c#, winforms

how i can make a loop timer that check if in main form topmost.enable is false until a label is visible and then set to true when the label deactive?

If tried this code but not work:

```
 private void InitializeAlive()
    {
        alive = new System.Timers.Timer();
        alive.Interval = 1000;
        alive.AutoReset = true;
        alive.Elapsed += Alive_Tick;
        alive.Start();
    }

    private void Alive_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblPassword.Enabled)
        {                
            this.TopMost = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
            alive.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPassword.Text == pswd)
        {
            TopMost = false;
            webPrintSetting.ShowPageSetupDialog();
            InitializeAlive();
        }
        else
        {
            btnPrint.Enabled = false;
            btnPrint.Visible = false;
            lblPassword.Visible = false;
            txtPassword.Enabled = false;
            txtPassword.Visible = false;
            txtPassword.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: WinForms should use a WinForm's Timer.

Comment: You never turn lblPassword.Enabled to true, or false. But you make an if statement for lblPassword.Enabled. Did you mean to do that, or is that if statement suppose to check lblPassword.Visible?

Comment: no, I do not need to enable or disable lblPassword. i need to check if enabled or disable for turn on topmost....

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do something when 'Enabled' property of the label changes, then you can simply add handler to the 'EnabledChanged' property, like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lblPassword.EnabledChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.LblPassword_EnabledChanged);
}
```

And implement the handler like this:

```
private void LblPassword_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TopMost = !lblPassword.Enabled;
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but i need before to verify a password.

Comment: Then try to ask somebody to formulate the question properly, otherwise it's impossible to help you... sorry.

Comment: I know. I've create a function in an winform topmost enabled that show some controls (also lblPassword) needed to check proper password. Then winform must be set topmost disabled until a showdialog form is shown. For this i need the timer to monitor

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to toggle on/off topmost (off until a target process is running).

```
private Timer check;

public MyForm()
{
InitializeCheck();
}

private void InitializeCheck()
{
check = new Timer();
check.Interval = 5000;
check.Tick += Check_Tick;
check.Enabled = false;
}

private void Check_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
CheckProgram();
}

private void CheckProgram()
{
Process[] program = rocess.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
if (program.Length == 0)
{
check.Enabled = false;
TopMost = true;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
TopMost = false;
check.Enabled = true;
}
```